# Cannot serializing sorted dictionary to JSON - Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, foundation

Cannot serialize my sorted dictionary into JSON via `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:options:)`

Serialization works with unsorted dictionary, but with sorted app throws error with description:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'
```

Here is how my method looks like:

```
func createJSONFile(){
    // create path to json file
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = urls[0] as NSURL
    guard let jsonURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("graphData") else {
        print("Failed to create path to json file.")
        return
    }

    print(jsonURL.absoluteString)
    // creating a .json file in the Documents folder
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: jsonURL.absoluteString){
      fileManager.createFile(atPath: jsonURL.absoluteString, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        print("file created")
    }

    do {
        let unsortedDic = self.tempDictionaryForJsonFile
        let sortedDic = unsortedDic.sorted(by: <)
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: sortedDic, options: .prettyPrinted)
        print(jsonData)
        try jsonData.write(to: jsonURL)

        print(fileManager.fileExists(atPath: jsonURL.absoluteString))

        let content = try String.init(contentsOf: jsonURL, encoding: .utf8)
        print(content)

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

It is interesting that in inspector while debugging unsorted dictionary looks like this: [unsorted dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HR5G.png) and sorted looks like this [sorted dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCq4s.png)

Please help in solving this issue.

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't have any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are no sorted directories in Swift stdlib (or in JSON for that matter; JSON objects are unordered). When you call `.sorted()` on a dictionary, it returns an array of key/value pairs `[(Key, Value)]`.

`JSONSerialization` has rules about what it can serialize:

- The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
- All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
- All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
- Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

There are implicit bridges from NS-compatible collections to their NS equivalent, but you only get this if the contents can be expressed in ObjC (and `(Key, Value)` can't be).

How to implement this correctly depends heavily on the type and contents of `tempDictionaryForJsonFile` which aren't given here. It also depends on what you're trying to achieve with a "sorted dictionary" (which doesn't exist in JSON, so there's no way to get to it from Swift). If you mean "an ordered array of JSON objects, each with one key/value," that can be built (but you'll need to support it in whatever is consuming this data).

Comment: Thanks for information! My task is to have JSON file with X and Y audio plot in the end. For clarity, I extract sample rate from audio file during playback then append each value of sample rate in the moment of time to [Float] array. Then I run through this [Float] array with .enumerate and construct a dictionary which keys are Indexes of [Float] array casted to String and values are array's respective values also casted to String. At the end it turns out this output dictionary has unordered keys.

Comment: "At the end it turns out this output dictionary has unordered keys." Correct. All Swift dictionaries have unordered keys (and JSON objects have unordered keys). Was that meant as a question? It's unclear why you would convert any of these numbers into Strings; that's very strange and error prone (and wouldn't sort correctly if you mean to sort). This seems very convoluted. If you have `[Float]` already, why not just serialize that? Or `[Record]`, where `Record` would have sample time, X and Y floats?

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. Before you posted it I have managed to serialize graph data to [[String: Float]] array, where String is an index of Y value (Float) of graph, therefore I have a JSON file with contents like: [
  {
    "index" : value
  }, {"index": value ...}. It was a part of test task for job interview.